# Access specific value in matrix based on row/column information

Tags: matrix

Given this Matrix

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 92.355, 49.}, {1, 7, 86.7407, 46.5}, {6, 2, 
  92.355, 49.}, {6, 7, 87.237, 46.5}}
```

How can I automatically access the third column entry in the row where the first entry is 1 and the second is 7 (86.7407)?

This automatisation really should look at the first two entries of the rows and then give back the third column number in that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
m={{0,0,0,0},{1,2,92.355,49.},{1,7,86.7407,46.5},{6,2,92.355,49.},{6,7,87.237,46.5}};
Cases[m,{1,7,__}][[1,3]]
```

which should return 86.7407

The `Cases` with that pattern will find all rows matching the first two elements and then the `[[1,3]]` will extract the third element from the first matching row.

Comment: Thank you Roman and Bill!

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 92.355, 49.}, {1, 7, 86.7407, 46.5},
        {6, 2, 92.355, 49.}, {6, 7, 87.237, 46.5}};

FirstCase[data, {1, 7, x_, ___} -> x]
(*    86.7407    *)
```